# docopt's argument dictionary flags show the value of their arguments instead of True/False

Tags: python, command-line-interface, docopt

I have a docopt docstring in my python program that looks something like this:

```
"""
program.py

Usage:
  program.py (-h | --help)
  program.py --version
  program.py word2vec DIRECTORY [-u MODEL] [-v]
  program.py word2vec DIRECTORY [-o OUTPUTMODEL] [-v]
  program.py tsneplot <model> <word> [-s <dest> <plotname>]

Options:
  -h --help               Show this screen.
  --version               Show version.
  -o OUTPUTMODEL          Specify the name of the output model
  -s <dest> <plotname>    Specify the destination folder and the name of the plot to be saved (for the tsne command)
  -u MODEL                Specify the name of the model to update
  -v                      Verbose output

"""
```

When I try a command

```
python program.py word2vec rootfolder -o outputmodel
```

the output arguments dictionary is of the form

```
{'--help': False,
 '--version': False,
 '-o': 'outputmodel',
 '-s': None,
 '-u': None,
 '-v': False,
 '<model>': None,
 '<plotname>': None,
 '<word>': None,
 'DIRECTORY': 'rootfolder',
 'tsneplot': False,
 'word2vec': True}
```

The problem over here is that instead of giving a `True` value to the `-o` flag it gives the `-o` flag a value that should instead be in the `OUTPUTMODEL` key. In other words the `-o` flag gets the value of the argument and the argument `OUTPUTMODEL`'s key is itself absent. The same happens when I try a commmand that looks like this:

```
 python program.py word2vec rootfolder -u updatedmodel
```

The output dictionary :

```
   {'--help': False,
 '--version': False,
 '-o': None,
 '-s': None,
 '-u': 'updatedmodel',
 '-v': False,
 '<model>': None,
 '<plotname>': None,
 '<word>': None,
 'DIRECTORY': 'rootfolder',
 'tsneplot': False,
 'word2vec': True}
```

The '-u' flag is being assigned the value of its argument, and the argument `MODEL` (as shown in Usage) is absent.

And a similar thing happens with the -s flag in the command

```
program.py tsneplot <model> <word> [-s <dest> <plotname>]
```

The `-s` flag gets the value of the `<dest>` argument, and the `<dest>` argument's key is absent in the dictionary.

It was working alright some moments ago until I made some minor changes. I have tried to look at the docstring and read the documentation but can't figure out where I could be wrong since I did seem to have specified the option descriptions correctly. Could anyone please help me figure out the issue?

Comment: *"the `-o` flag gets the value of the argument"* - that's exactly what I'd expect to happen! Note that `None` is falsey and a non-empty string is truthy, so you can still do e.g. `if args['-o']:` and get the correct behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Aha! Thanks so much! One confusion though. When I first tried a similar docstring, it was giving a `True` value to the `-o` flag and argument value to the `OUTPUTMODEL` key. And the test example in the docopt documentation also gave a similar result. So, why doesn't the OUTPUTMODEL gets created as a key when it is supposed to be an argument?

Comment: Can you roll back your changes? Did you update the module?

Comment: Nope, I didn't update. I did try to make it as far back to the initial stages as possible and the above code represents that one. The only extra thing in the above docstring is the last command in `Usage`. I just tried to work with your solution and its working. So, the only thing that troubles me is what if it went back to working the way it was working initially. The program will crash.

Comment: @dsgdfg Sorry, I didn't understand. How can python take the args? Aren't args supposed to be parsed by docopt which gives an arguments dictionary? Are you saying something is going wrong with this parsing?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgotten the `<...>` signs around `DIRECTORY`. Try this:

```
"""
program.py

Usage:
  program.py (-h | --help)
  program.py --version
  program.py word2vec <DIRECTORY> [-u MODEL] [-v]
  program.py word2vec <DIRECTORY> [-o OUTPUTMODEL] [-v]
  program.py tsneplot <model> <word> [-s <dest> <plotname>]

Options:
  -h --help               Show this screen.
  --version               Show version.
  -o OUTPUTMODEL          Specify the name of the output model
  -s <dest> <plotname>    Specify the destination folder and the name of the plot to be saved (for the $
  -u MODEL                Specify the name of the model to update
  -v                      Verbose output
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried it but it gives the same output. Over [here](http://docopt.org/) it seems to say that an argument can be written in caps: `Words starting with "<", ending with ">" or upper-case words are interpreted as positional arguments.` So, `DIRECTORY` doesn't really need angled brackets does it?

Comment: Ah, you are right. So "<...>" wouldn't make any difference.